# How to get from Gdynia or Gdansk to Leba

Tags: buses, poland, gdansk

I was expecting a train to go. But, no matter where I look there is no train connecting the two cities. Nor a bus.

I based my assumption on
https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Gdynia/%C5%81eba
which states there should be a train. Other sources also refer to trains.

I expected to find the connection on either
https://www.intercity.pl/en/
or
https://rozklad-pkp.pl/en
Both display 'no route found'.

I checked Flixbus and Blablacar, both with no success.

I really want to go to Slowinski Park Narodowy over the weekend.
Does anyone know how I could get there - taxi would cost 75€ one-way, according to rome2rio.

UPDATE
I verified the top answer ([Cuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/163273/117131)).
Currently there are cunstruction works at Lebork - to find the bus, exit the train station to your left. The buses have a sign telling you where they go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are connections, you can find plenty of them on [e-podroznik.pl](https://www.e-podroznik.pl/). Most (all?) of them are the same:

- Gdańsk Główny (main station) to Lębork by train (regional or Intercity), cost: 16 PLN
- Lębork to Łeba by bus (Trede TRANS or Boguś BUS), cost: 12 PLN

It takes 2-3 hours depending on the connection and there's a train leaving Gdańsk. Total price is 28 PLN (around 6€).

Both websites that you mentioned only look for trains and they're not aware that there are buses going to Łeba, that's why you weren't able to find any connection.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me out a lot

Answer (score 1):

Check https://www.e-podroznik.pl/

I see plenty of options there with a connection in Lębork.

Comment: Thank you! This is also correct but because Kuba was first he retains 'correct answer'

Comment: That's ok. Was the trip worth it?

Comment: Yes, definitely! If you really want to know, check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Unfci_IHhSc or shorter, best of here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVSTTMWrYsM